# Why can't a port remain open?

Tags: c

Story : I open a business and there is the `Door 91` which will allow customers to come in : `listen(Path_to_Me, 5);`. If a customer comes in, I accept them in : `Me_and_Them = accept(Path_to_Me, (struct sockaddr *) &Their_Address, &sin_len);` and I print their Address : `printf("Their Address : [%s]\n", inet_ntoa(Their_Address.sin_addr));` Then I write a message to the customer : `write(Me_and_Them, response, sizeof(response) - 1);` and then I close the door of my business : `close(Me_and_Them);` so that the connection between me and the customer is closed.

Question : Why does the door of my business have to be closed in order to close a connection between me and my customer ? Why can't the customer simply leave from the door and leave the door open for other possible costumers to continue coming in ?

```
int main() {

    int one = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in My_Address, Their_Address;
    socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(Their_Address);

    int Path_to_Me = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    setsockopt(Path_to_Me, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

    int Door = 91;

    My_Address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    My_Address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    My_Address.sin_port = htons(Door);

    bind(Path_to_Me, (struct sockaddr *) &My_Address, sizeof(My_Address));

    listen(Path_to_Me, 5);

    int Me_and_Them;

    Me_and_Them = accept(Path_to_Me, (struct sockaddr *) &Their_Address, &sin_len);
    printf("Their Address : [%s]\n", inet_ntoa(Their_Address.sin_addr));

    char response[] = "test\n";
    write(Me_and_Them, response, sizeof(response) - 1);
    close(Me_and_Them);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The door is still open. When you call `accept` on `Path_to_Me`, [the original socket is unaffected](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html). Calling `accept` again as you have called it will create a client socket for the next client waiting to communicate with your listening server.

Comment: Please note that this question is not about ports remaining open, it is about connections remaining open.  The port is specified as part of `My_Address` in the call to `bind()`, which does ***not*** need to be repeated in order to handle multiple remote parties.

Answer (score 0):

Analogies between real life and the inner workings of software, or anything technological for that matter, are generally avoided for good reason: they might seem enticing when you look at them superficially, but they break down in all sorts of horrible ways as soon as you dive in a bit deeper than the surface.  Also, they are so treacherous that even at the superficial level they do not help at all: the amount of mental housekeeping that you have to do in order to maintain the analogy is like adding one more dimension to the complexity of the problem at hand.  So, my advice is: forget the real life analogies, think technically and only technically.

The concept of a "connection" exists because the underlying system (the Internet Protocol stack) needs it for housekeeping purposes. In the "connection" the system keeps various things like the IP address of the remote party, a buffer in which it is receiving data from the remote party until an entire packet has been completed so that the packet can then be delivered to you as one piece, error-correcting information such as a packet id so that the stack knows whether it has missed a packet or is receiving a duplicate packet, etc.

All this information is crucial, and it pertains to communication with only that one specific remote party.  When another party comes in, they will have a different IP address, you don't want their data mixed with the previous guy's data, and you want a new packet sequence for error correction.  In other words, you need a new connection.  That's what connections are all about, and that's why a different connection must be established with each individual remote party.